# Stitching game screenshots into one image with border detection

Tags: photo-stitching

I have alot of small screenshots of map (from game). They all overlap at some point, so It's possible to manually overlap them to almost 100% identical results. I can't zoom out to see 100% of map, so I screenshot parts of map.

I want o stitch them (preferrably via commandline) with detection of overlapping images.

Tried Hugin, but it distorts normal screenshots on some kind of sphere which is what I don't want. Doesn't seem to have any support for isometric images without perspective

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer helps you: https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/112883

It is very unhandy but works (sometimes).